# How can I get result with array in Sympy

Tags: arrays, plot, contour, sympy

I am tring to get countour chart with sympy
I'm tring something like below but subs does not take array

and I tried for lambapy but lamdafy does not take 2 symbols or I don't know how to.

```
X,Y, formula = symbols('X Y formula')
formula = sp.sympify('X*2 + Y*3 +7*X*Y +34')
x = numpy.arange(1,10,1)
y = numpy.arange(1,10,1)

XValue,YValue = meshgrid(x,y)

ZValue = formula.sub([(X,XValue),(Y,YValue)])
Plot.contour(XValue, YValue, ZValue)
```

Are there any way to get result form 2 or more symbol with arrays

Comment: The docstring for `lambdify` answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to lambdify the formula and get the result Z first. Then put XYZ value into the chart

```
X,Y, formula = symbols('X Y formula')
formula = sp.sympify('X*2 + Y*3 +7*X*Y +34')
x = numpy.arange(1,10,1)
y = numpy.arange(1,10,1)

XValue,YValue = meshgrid(x,y)

T = lambdify((x,y), formula,'numpy')
ZValue = T(XValue,YValue )

Plot.contour(XValue, YValue, ZValue)
```